# How to send a POST or GET request with BODY depending on API type

Tags: ios, json, swift, request, alamofire

I have create a class Network Manager the allows to share the instance of response over controllers. Depending on controller type I call the API which is defined as method GET however in some case it requires a POST method to send the server and wait for response start with the authentication of granting token.

In Network Manager class I created function callingHttpRequest

```
   func callingHttpRequest(params:Dictionary<String,Any>, apiname:String,cuurentView:UIViewController,taskCallback: @escaping (Int,
        AnyObject?) -> Void)  {

        let urlString  = HOST_NAME + apiname

        print("url",urlString)
        print("params", params)
        Alamofire.request(urlString,method: .get,parameters:params).validate().responseJSON { response in
            switch response.result {
            case .success(let resultData):
                taskCallback(1,resultData as AnyObject)
                break
            case .failure(let error):

                 let returnData = String(data: response.data! , encoding: .utf8)
                 print("returnData" ,returnData)
                print("request URL", response.request)

                if !Connectivity.isConnectedToInternet(){
                    NetworkManager.sharedInstance.dismissLoader()
                    cuurentView.view.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
                    let AC = UIAlertController(title: "Warning", message: error.localizedDescription, preferredStyle: .alert)
                    let okBtn = UIAlertAction(title: "Retry", style: .default, handler: {(_ action: UIAlertAction) -> Void in
                        taskCallback(2, "" as AnyObject)
                    })
                    let noBtn = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .destructive, handler: {(_ action: UIAlertAction) -> Void in
                    })
                    AC.addAction(okBtn)
                    AC.addAction(noBtn)
                    cuurentView.present(AC, animated: true, completion: { _ in })
                }
                else{
                    let errorCode:Int = error._code;
                    if errorCode != -999 && errorCode != -1005{
                        NetworkManager.sharedInstance.dismissLoader()
                        cuurentView.view.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
                        let AC = UIAlertController(title: "Warning", message: error.localizedDescription, preferredStyle: .alert)
                        let okBtn = UIAlertAction(title: "Retry", style: .default, handler: {(_ action: UIAlertAction) -> Void in
                            taskCallback(2, "" as AnyObject)
                        })
                        let noBtn = UIAlertAction(title: "Cancel", style: .destructive, handler: {(_ action: UIAlertAction) -> Void in
                        })
                        AC.addAction(okBtn)
                        AC.addAction(noBtn)


                        cuurentView.present(AC, animated: true, completion: { _ in })
                   }else if errorCode == -1005{
                       NetworkManager.sharedInstance.dismissLoader()
                       taskCallback(2, "" as AnyObject)
                    }

                }
                break;

            }


        }

    }
```

While in ViewController I'm calling the function tokenRequest to create a token granted from server.

```
func tokenRequest(){
    var tokenRequest = [String:String]();
    tokenRequest["Authorization"] = token_auth;
    tokenRequest["token_id"] = "token_id";
    tokenRequest["token_id"] = "token_id";
    NetworkManager.sharedInstance.callingHttpRequest(params:tokenRequest, apiname:"feed/api/gettoken", cuurentView: self){val,responseObject in
        if val == 1{
            print("responseobjec", responseObject)
            let dict = responseObject as! NSDictionary
            sharedPrefrence.set(dict.object(forKey: "access_token") as! String, forKey: "access_token")
            sharedPrefrence.synchronize();
            self.callingHttppApi()
        }else if val == 2{
            NetworkManager.sharedInstance.dismissLoader()
            self.loginRequest()
        }
    }
}
```

By default Network Manager have `Alamofire.request(urlString,method: .get,parameters:params)` has the method get however the function tokenRequest needs the `method: .post`.

I add the method post in the function

```
NetworkManager.sharedInstance.callingHttpRequest(params:loginRequest, apiname:"feed/rest_api/gettoken&grant_type=client_credentials", method: .post, cuurentView: self
```

This returned an error "Extra argument 'method' in call".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `NetworkManager` method signature does not include `method` as an argument.

You have:

```
callingHttpRequest(params: Dictionary<String,Any>, 
                  apiname: String, 
              cuurentView: UIViewController, 
             taskCallback: @escaping (Int, AnyObject?) -> Void))
```

Yet you're trying to call it while passing an extra `method` argument which does not exist:

`callingHttpRequest(params:loginRequest,
                   apiname:"feed/rest_api/gettoken&grant_type=client_credentials", 
                    method: .post, // **Does not exist**
               cuurentView: self) 
              taskCallback: {})`

If you want to pass in a `method` you need to add that argument to your method in order to call it.

Comment: I tried that adding method in `callingHTTPRequest` didn't solve the problem at my end.

Comment: Seed I defined method as string in the func as following func `callingHttpRequest(params:Dictionary<String,Any>, apiname:String,cuurentView:UIViewController,method:String, taskCallback: @escaping (Int,
        AnyObject?) -> Void)  {` then I kept method as default `Alamofire.request(urlString,method: .get,parameters:params).validate().responseJSON { response` in the ViewController I added `method: .post` got `Type 'String' has no member 'post'`

Comment: That's a different error. My answer solved your first problem. Now you're problem is that you're passing in the wrong value. `method` is supposed to be of type `String`. You're trying to pass an enum case `.post`. Either you need to pass a `String` or change the argument to accept the type that you want to pass it.

Comment: I resolved the issue thanks by defining `method:HTTPMethod` instead which allowed me to pass `.post` or `.get` when needed.

Comment: Great, please upvote and/or accept my answer if it helped.